# How to scrape vessels from MarineTraffic

Tags: redirect, scrapy, user-agent, httpforbiddenhandler, ais

I try to extract data from https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:9829069/ using the following scrapy's spider and then I save the response to file.html.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

class MarinetrafficSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'marinetraffic'
    allowed_domains = ['marinetraffic.com']
    ua = UserAgent()
    ua.update()

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
                    'https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:9829069/'
            ]
        headers= {'User-Agent': self.ua['google chrome'] }
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, headers=headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        with open('file.html', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file')
```

But I don't take the expected response. The returned response is in [file.html](https://0bin.net/paste/v59af3PNRLOd+b5c#K-cpkR1uUWd2i65mW3oHVleTO/lq5FRpN7wjvmBNV62)

Please check the [debug](https://0bin.net/paste/PHsu3S9jf2kMjFiX#0ANwjOWHz4R2fYcFuYgRWMAiU3i2+3n93WEbL9ac2k4) results.

What modifications do I need to do on the above code so that the returned response be the same as the response I take from the browser?

I will apprisiate your notings.

Comment: If you right-click the page and click 'Save as...' you can download it as an .HTML file. Use a text editor and you can see it just as your browser would. But I assume you want to scrape multiple pages? This is just my suggestion if you don't have any other option. Let me know if you get the data you wanted.

Comment: You'll need to render the page using a headless browser to get a response that's similar to what you see in your browser. You can use Splash (https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this.

Comment: @dram95 Yes I want to scrape multiple pages in which imo number is variable (https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/details/ships/imo:...).

Comment: @WimHermans I will check Splash. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you do not see anything is that the website is rendered via JavaScript. In other words, MarineTraffic server sends you a very basic HTML page, along with a JS script that will load the content, construct and display the required HTML for you.

To get the full HTML, with the data you are looking for, you need to emulate a real browser. If you're using Python, you can have a look at [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), along with Chromedriver.

But beware, last time I checked (3 years ago) MarineTraffic had a very strong anti-crawler protection, that would block you after a couple pages visited with the Selenium + Chromedriver setup.